# Twitter Typeahead: undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter, typeahead.js

I have a .json file with data and I want to use Twitter's typeahead for the locations of railway stations in the .json file. (See my jsFiddle)
When I use the current code, I run into errors. On display, when I start typing, the results from typeahead is "undefined" for every record.

The problem is in the source method:

```
source: function(query, process){
                $.getJSON("../data/stations.json", function(data){
                    $.each(data.Stations.Station, function(key,val){
                        if(val.Land == "NL"){
                            stationsnamen.push(val['Namen'].Lang.toString());
                            stationsdata.push(new Array(val.Lat, val.Lon, val['Namen'].Lang.toString()));
                        }
                    });
                });
                process(stationsnamen);
            }
```

I can't seem to find why it is returning "undefined", as `process(array)` in the first-to-last line of code above gets the same data, compared to having a separate method.

[Current code](http://jsfiddle.net/4wjnscyb/)

[Example JSON](http://jsfiddle.net/fap0tojq/)

Comment: Show how station data looks like. What is returned when "../data/stations.json" is called.

Comment: I have added a jsFiddle with example JSON

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions in typeAhead should be an object rather than plain strings.

You have setup typeAhead to display 'value' property of object

```
displayKey: 'value'
```

The easiest way to solve this problem is to wrap source strings into JavaScript objects.

Like this:

```
stationsnamen.push({value: val['Namen'].Lang.toString() });
```